# A question based on intermediate fields and separability

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, separable-extension

This problem was asked in my Abstract algebra assignment and I was unable to solve it so I am asking for help here.

> Let E be an intermediate field .

> (a) If u $\in$ F is separable over K, then u is separable over E.

> (b) If F is separable over K, then F is separable over E and E is separable over K.

I tried (a) but couldn't solve it. The irreducible polynomial of u say f is given seperable over K which means that it only has single root. But I have no reason to believe why it  is also seperable over E.

For (b) F is seperable over K means that all elements of F are seperable over K then using (a) I can deduce that F is seperable over E but why E must be seperable over K. Also if x$\in E$ implies that $x \in F$ and so x is separable over K. So it's done . But for (a) i need help.

Kindly help me with this question!

Comment: Hint for (a): The minimal polynomial of $u$ over $E$ is a divisor of the minimal polynomial over $K$. Note for (b): If $F/K$ is separable, then certainly $E/K$ also is, since $E\subseteq F$ (if you take any $u\in E$, then $u\in F$ hence separable over $K$)

Comment: @leoli1 "The minimal polynomial of u over E is a divisor of the minimal polynomial over K" why would that happen? Can you explain that in detail? (b) part i have done

Comment: Call the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $E$ $p$ and over $K$ $q$. Then $q$ is also a polynomial over $E$ with $q(u)=0$ and therefore $p\mid q$ (since $p$ generates the ideal in $E[x]$ consisting of all those polynomials over $E$ that have a zero at $u$)

Comment: @leoli1 Thanks! done.